# Contour Integral and Removable Singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, singularity

Could someone check if what I have done is correct?

To evaluate $\int_{C}\dfrac{z^3}{2z-i}$ where $C$ is the unit circle.

My solution is as follows:

Let $f(z):=\dfrac{z^3}{2z-i}$.
There seems to be a singularity at $z=\frac{i}{2}$, but it lies in the unit circle; Hence, I don't seem to be able to apply Cauchy-goursat, but I think it is a removable singularity, so I do the following.

Rewriting $f(z)$ as $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{2}{z^2}(1-i/2z)^{-1}$, Now we can expand this as a geometric series, thus we have $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{2}{z^2}[1-i/2z + (i/2z)^2+\dots]$

This function is complex differentible in the unit disc, hence by cauchy-goursat the integral over the unit circle is zero.

EDIT: I haven't yet reached Cauchy's Integral Formula, So am not allowed to use it yet.

Following Kavi Ramamurthy's idea:

Since $\int_{C}\dfrac{1}{z^n}=0$ for $n>1$ , and $\int_{C}z^n=0$ for $n\geq0$, we see that the integral simplifies to $\int_C \frac{-i}{16z}$ whose value is $\frac{\pi}{8}$.

Comment: What makes the series differentiable? The answer in fact is not $0$.

Comment: I forgot, It's a series in terms of $1/z$ and not in $z$ so I can't take it to be differentiable. Sorry I'll try it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you integrate the series you obtained term by term you will find that all but one term integrates to $0$. The answer is $\int_C \frac {z^{2}} 2 (\frac i {2z})^{3} dz=\frac {\pi} 8$.

Answer (score 1):

Since$$\int_C\frac{z^3}{2z-i}\,\mathrm dz=\frac12\int_C\frac{z^3}{z-i/2}\,\mathrm dz,$$Cauchy's integral formula tells us that your integral is iqual to$$\frac122\pi i\left(\frac i2\right)^3=\frac\pi8.$$

Comment: I forgot to mention, but I am not to use Cauchy's integral formula yet. It appears later on in the book I am following.